# Combining cron schedules spread over 2 months

Tags: cron

I have a cron task I want to schedule to run every day at 10am from 20th November to 10th December.

I'm doing this by scheduling the task twice, one from 20th November to 30th November (0 0 10 20-30 NOV ?) and again from 1st December to 10th December (0 0 10 1-10 DEC ?).

Is there any way to combine "0 0 10 20-30 NOV ?" and "0 0 10 1-10 DEC ?" together so I can have just one task and achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [crontab.guru](http://crontab.guru), these schedules can't be combined. But you could schedule it for every day and have your command make sure it's only running between those dates.

```
0 10 * 11,12 * TODAY=`date +"%m%d"`; [ $TODAY -ge 1120 -a $TODAY -le 1210 ] && rest_of_your_command
```

Today (October 23rd), the value of TODAY would be 1023 which is not between 1120 and 1210, so your command wouldn't run.